# How to deal with rejected migrations?

Tags: discussion, migration, closed-questions

As of now, the site has over 100 [rejected migrations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3A1+migrated%3A0+duplicate%3A0): questions that were migrated here and then closed. They are *locked*, so can be neither deleted nor answered, nor improved.

This is particularly unfortunate because some such questions come up in search results ([this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31481/79865) has over 5000 views), damaging both the image of Web Apps and possibly its Google rank (as the visitors will immediately go back, seeing nothing useful here).

I think the site would be better off without most of rejected migrations, in particular unanswered one. Is there a better way to deal with them than going around flagging for mod attention?

Comment: I don't think it's that damaging to the site, but these *are* annoying. You flag 'em, we'll bag 'em (just preferably not all at once).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287891/21960):

> Starting [December 10, 2016], these should be deleted automatically 30 days after being rejected.
>
> Note that this logic will only delete a rejected, migrated question if it meets the following criteria:
>
> - Migrated from another site (and no moderator has cleared the migration history)
> - Not already deleted
> - Closed (but not as a duplicate)
> - Locked

And, indeed, I've seen a lot of these old stubs are gone, including the specific one referenced in the original question.

So the answer is: There is nothing for us *to* do; the system will take care of the vast majority. As always, use flags for those outliers that can't be handled automatically.

Comment: you might want to edit for style, but there it is.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually not *that* bad - here're some stats;

193 migrations in the last 90 days

superuser.com                                    →  webapps.stackexchange.com × 97; 16% rejected
programmers.stackexchange.com    → webapps.stackexchange.com × 2
lifehacks.stackexchange.com          → webapps.stackexchange.com × 2
webmasters.stackexchange.com     → webapps.stackexchange.com × 2
stackoverflow.com                            → webapps.stackexchange.com × 1
cs.stackexchange.com                     → webapps.stackexchange.com × 1
serverfault.com                                  →webapps.stackexchange.com × 1

Bulk of the migrations have come over from Super User, with a 16% rejection rate that translates to about 15 questions over 90 days.

There is a open [feature-request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) question on Meta Stack Exchange - [Provide direct feedback for rejected migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/provide-direct-feedback-for-rejected-migrations) - hopefully with this implemented, it should give users a better feedback.

I was also under the impression that rejected migrations are cleaned up via an automated process, that doesn't seem to be the case.

For now, just flag them via custom Mod flag & us Moderators will take care of it